# Binding user control to object proporties with minimal effort

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, user-controls

I have user control:

```
<UserControl>
    <TextBox Name="TB1"/>
    <TextBox Name="TB2"/>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
  public TwoStrings TsObj { get; set; }
  public MyControl()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
  }
}
```

Where

```
public class TwoStrings
{
    string S1 { get; set; }
    string S2 { get; set; }
}
```

How to bind TsObj.S1 to TB1.Text and TsObj.S2 to TB2.Text with minimal code changes? TwoStrings should not be changed. Updates on object should reflect on control. Code example please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of resources about wpf/silverlight databinding on the internet, even here in stackoverflow. But long story short, you can simply do this:

```xml
<UserControl>
  <TextBox Name="TB1" Text="{Binding S1}" />
  <TextBox Name="TB2" Text="{Binding S2}"/>
</UserControl>
```

```cs
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public TwoStrings TsObj { get; set; }
    public MyControl()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      this.DataContext = TsObj = new TwoStrings();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Note that if you change properties via code in the TwoStrings instance, that will be not reflected in the textboxes, because you'll need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in TwoStrings (which is the ViewModel - VM in the MVVM pattern) to get two way databinding. Otherwise, you'll get only one way databinding from your textbox to the properties on the datacontext (TwoString)

Comment: Thx. All other ways that I could think of were more complicated. INotifyPropertyChanged should be implemented where?